# Character pointer adding random values while attaching string characters

Tags: c

I am using following code to print md5 and creating a string

```
char *hash = (char*)malloc(32 * sizeof(char));
unsigned *d = md5(msg, strlen(msg));
MD5union u;
printf("\n\n\nThe MD5 code for input string is : \n");
for (j=0;j<4; j++){
    u.w = d[j];
    for (k=0;k<4;k++) 
    {
        char *mVal = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
        sprintf(mVal, "%02x",u.b[k]);
        strcat(hash, mVal);
        printf("%02x",u.b[k]);
    }
}

printf("\n\n\nThe MD5 code for input string is :%s \n", hash);
```

My output is

```
The MD5 code for input string is : 
187ef4436122d1cc2f40dc2b92f0eba0


The MD5 code for input string is :p��187ef4436122d1cc2f40dc2b92f0eba0
```

Why is there `p��` extra in my hash value

Comment: `mVal` is only one byte in size, but you are trying to sprintf several characters to it, hence you have UB. Make it at least 3 bytes if you need it to hold two hex chars plus a 0 terminator,

Comment: so  3 * sizeof(char)  and "%02x\0" @PaulR not working either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hash` is not initialized. It can have any initial value. `strcat` *appends* the data. If there is something in `hash` that qualifies as null terminated string, it will not be removed. Use `strcpy` or zero-initialize `hash` before use.

Except for that, there are multiple errors with your code and undefined behaviors.

1. `malloc(32 * sizeof(char));` allocates memory for 31 (not 32) characters length string when including null termination character. If you want to store md5 there as a string, allocate 33 bytes of memory.
2. `char *mVal = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
       sprintf(mVal, "%02x",u.b[k]);` - there is place for 0 (not 1, not 2, but zero) length string in the memory pointed to `mVal`. Is you wan to store the output of `sprintf, "%02x"` to a variable, allocate at least 3 bytes of memory - first byte for the first hex digit, second byte for the second hex digit and the third byte for null termination character.
3. `char *mVal = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));` is nowhere freed before it runs out of scope and just leaks memory.
4. Looks like you are using [md5hash.c](https://github.com/NachiketNamjoshi/CryptoStuff/blob/master/md5hash.c). The function returns a pointer to a `static` memory. This is bad, as it makes the function not reentrant.
5. Your program could be rewritten as just:
   `char *hash = malloc(33); unsigned *d = md5(msg, strlen(msg)); snprintf(hash, 33, "%08x%08x%08x%08x", d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3]);`. There is little need for converting `unsigned int` to `unsigned char` when printing hex, you can to that directly with `%08x`. And `unsigned char` is converted back to `int` when passing as `printf` argument. And you can just `sprintf` directly into `hash`, no need for temporary variables.
6. Using a union to convert between `unsigned int` array to bytes feels like a misuse of the tool. (On most systems) you can just cast the pointer `char *d_as_char = (void*)d;` and access `d_as_char` as `4 * sizeof(int)` length char array. If you really want to not have undefined behavior and aliasing problems in your code, use the `memcpy` way: `char d_as_array[sizeof(int) * 4]; memcpy(d_as_array, d, sizeof(d_as_array));`

Comment: That's one of those "where do I start?" questions... Well done.

Comment: Missed out that in C `malloc` should not be casted. Just too lazy to look up the reference. I leave that to the reader.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc - Not that lay aferall

Comment: @kamil your 5th doesn't seem to be working it seems, :43f47e18ccd122612bdc402fa0ebf092 has numbers mirrored,

Comment: @muhammadumar Och right, endianess. You could just call a conversion function, like from [bswap.h](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bswap.3.html) on unix, or just type-pune to char pointer and make one long `sprintf` call.